# How to generate a valid signed JWT for a GCP service account with a private key?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, jwt, google-api-gateway

I have created a GCP Service account followed by generating a key for it.
I have a GCP cloud function
I also have an API Gateway configured to talk to my backend service.
The service account has the permission access to the API Gateway. I have defined the securityDefinition for that service account in my API gateway OpenSpec config file
Now I just have to generate a signed JWT for that service account (for testing from my localhost using postman), pass it to the API gateway api or to the cloud function call as a bearer token and it should work.

I created JWT Using [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) and it worked for API Gateway but not for Cloud function. For cloud function it gives 401 unauthorized, even though it has all the required permission.

But when i generate JWT for the same service accoount using `gcloud auth print-identity-token`, it works for cloud function but not for API Gateway. For API Gateway it gives 401 unauthorized : Jwt issuer is not configured, error.

On comparing both the JWTs payload I noticed that
**The JWT using jsonwebtoken**, has proper `iss` configured since I mentioned it programatically in NodeJS using npm library. But it's npt getting signed properly i.e. it's missing `email` and `email_verified` attribute.
**The jwt using gcloud library** , has `email` and `email_verified` attribute, which means its properly signed but the `iss` doesn't match with the one configured in openspec `serviceDefinitions` section for API Gateway.

I need help in generating a proper signed token with my own `iss` configured in it.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: 1) There are two types of tokens: `access tokens` and `identity tokens`. You must create the correct type of token for the service you are calling. Since you do not include any code, I can only guess what you created with `jsonwebtoken`. My guess is that you created an `access token`. The command `gcloud auth print-identity-token` creates an OIDC Identity Token. Cloud Functions require an OIDC Identity Token.

Comment: 2) You state: `even though it has all the required permission`. What permissions and how? Only access tokens have permissions attached to the token. Permissions are granted to an Identity token by the service (Cloud Functions). The important items are which permissions and where did you assign them.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, Thanks for the response. I am sort of new to this GCP World. Can you please help me understand, how to decide of type of token? I want to access API Gateway and cloud function from my backend service running on cloudbuild . Secondly I want to test the integration from postman , so i need bearer token for the same, which I am not sure how to generate

Comment: For Stackoverflow, show your code, the error and stacktrace. Otherwise, we have to guess what you did. You must review the Authorization requirements for each API or service. In general, APIs require OAuth Access Tokens. Compute services require OIDC Identity Tokens. I have written many articles about OAuth in Google Cloud and answered several hundred questions here. There are other excellent blogs as well. You can also search for Stackoverflow answers from me and another expert (https://stackoverflow.com/users/11372593/guillaume-blaquiere) on Google Cloud authorization and identity.